# Do investigators regain sanity from slaying creatures?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu-7e, sanity

I could have sworn that killing a monster would allow investigators to gain sanity equal to the loss that seeing the monster incurs.

However, searching through the CoC 7th edition rulebook, I can find no mention of this. Is it true that investigators can regain some sanity this way?

Comment: So you know that you're not, like, imagining it or anything, that rule *is* on pages 28 and 30 of 2nd edition (1983). (Don't laugh! It's the only edition I have!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No

The 7e rulebook states clearly on pp.167-168 that there are 4 ways to regain sanity:

1. Keeper Award
2. Increasing a skill to 90%
3. Psychotherapy
4. Self-help (which cannot include mythos, thus excluding monster-slaying)

Comment: Ok, reading through the book, it looks like the "keeper award" is taking the place of sanity regain from killing monsters in 7th edition. The given example even talks about defeating monsters. The main difference seems to be that you only get the award at the end of a chapter or session, not upon killing the monster. I wonder if this causes more sanity loss in 7th edition or is this change balanced out by other changes to the sanity system?

Comment: It certainly *used* to be the case, but **not** in 7e. The last version of the rules prior to 7e that I have is 5e, and in that it states: “When an investigator defeats, dispels, or slaughters something strange and alien […] his or her confidence naturally increases. The game reflects that as an increase in Sanity points. […] Such a reward should not exceed the Sanity loss roll for encountering the thing. If several or many such things were defeated, then award the maximum points for encountering the thing.” I can't vouch for 6e, but 1e - 5e allowed SAN increase via this method. Just not 7e.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at modules before 7E say things like 'if the investigators manage to slay the beast, award them maximum san' with no mention of what that is. Clearly there is meant to be a standard but i believe it was always intended to be at the end of a scenario or chapter.